# What to do if I lose my SSH key for an Amazon EC2 EBS backed instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have lost my SSH key, I  want to access my Amazon EC2 EBS backed instance.

Comment: As of ~2018/2019, you can login via Sessions Manager or EC2 Instance Connect. With these you can login without a keypair, allowing you to upload a new public key to the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- stop the instance
- detach the root volume
- attach the root volume to another instance as an EBS storage volume
- edit the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file with your new key
- move the volume back to the stopped instance
- start the instance and SSH with the new key

or

Run the **AWSSupport-ResetAccess** automation document in SSM

Comment: Since you mentioned SSM, why not use browser login through **SSM Session Manager**? Could avoid all this detaching volumes, stopping instance, and fix your files directly through browser in few minutes.